# How to change line width when plotting a locfit object in R?

Tags: r, plot

This sounds like a really basic question and it probably is but I can't figure out how to change the line width when plotting a `locfit` object. If you do a simple test, such as:

```
plot(locfit::locfit(~rnorm(n = 1000)))
```

and compare it with

```
plot(locfit::locfit(~rnorm(n = 1000)), lwd = 2.0)
```

You will see that the plotted line has the same thickness in both plots. So using `lwd` does not work when plotting a `locfit` object? Is there any workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: What package is `locfit` from? That does not appear to be a base R function.

Comment: @MrFlick sorry, you are right, my bad! It's from a package called locfit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use your model to `predict` the output to use `lines` on an empty `plot` which makes it possible to change the linewidth with `lwd` like this:

```r
library(locfit)
#> locfit 1.5-9.7    2023-01-02
set.seed(7)
fit <- locfit(~rnorm(n = 1000))
plot(fit)
```

[image]

```r
set.seed(7)
xvalues <- seq(min(rnorm(n = 1000)), max(rnorm(n = 1000)), length.out = 100)
pred <- predict(fit, xvalues)
plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(-3, 3), ylim=c(0, 0.4))
lines(xvalues, pred, lwd = 10)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is a nice workaround and it works, thanks! Although it would be more difficult to use when you don't have a good ideia of the ranges of the distribution

Comment: @JoãoCarvalho Then you might do `plot(fit)` first, use `par('usr')` to get the *x* and *y* limits from the resulting plot, and then draw the customized plot following Quinten's approach with these limits.

Answer (score 2):

There is not currently a way to do that in the existing function.  When you call `plot()` on the `locfit` object, it calls `preplot.locift()` on your object, and then `plot.preplot.locfit()` which calls `plot.locfit.1d()`.  The relevant lines from the code are:

```r
    plot(xev[ord], yy[ord], type = "n", xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, 
      main = main, xlim = range(x$xev[[1]]), ylim = ylim, 
      ...)
  }
  lines(xev[ord], yy[ord], type = type, lty = lty, col = col)
```

As you can see, the `...` goes through to the `plot` function, but the line actually gets added with `lines()` which does not have access to other arguments specified in `...`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It makes sense but I wish they would add that option to the existing function

Comment: The description file says that the maintainer is Andy Liaw `andy_liaw@merck.com`, you could e-mail and ask for that to be included in the next version.